# Get date from Carbon function Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, foreach, php-carbon

I use Laravel5 Carbon function:

$carbon_today= Carbon::today();

after dd($carbon_today) get this:

```
Carbon {#200 ▼
  +"date": "2015-07-10 00:00:00"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "UTC"
}
```

And it is fine. Now I need to use only date from CArbon,to put in variable. Try with foreach,

```
foreach ($carbon_today as $row) {
    $x= $row['date'];
  dd($x);
}
```

no succes

Comment: $carbon_today= Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d G:H:i'); resolve problem! Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop over it just use it like

```
$carbon_today= Carbon::today();
return $carbon_today;
```

you will get the date today in $carbon_today variable

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$today = Carbon::today();;
echo $today;
```

or

```
$today = Carbon::today()->toDateTimeString();
echo $today;
```

[Read More](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)